# Can I use my Wild Card SSL certificate in Apache and IIS?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, azure

I have an Azure Virtual machine.  I am hosting Confluence and a couple of IIS sites on the same machine.  Can I use a wild card ssl certificate from a reputable CA on the Confluence site (Apache/Tomcat) and also use the same cert on some of my IIS sites?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. There's nothing stopping you from using the same cert for multiple services/software. As long as clients connect with the name that matches the cert, you're good.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You could even use it on multiple servers as long as

- all the hostnames matches the certificate.
- all servers also share the corresponding private key.

Answer (score 3):

You can use same Wildcard certificate at the different server but you can only secure domains listed under for example, ***.mydomain.com** (I meant the domain on which you have issued wildcard SSL as well as its all sub domains).

Answer (score 1):

Please note that some *"reputable CA's"*<sup>1</sup> will "license" their certificates only for  single server usage and charge you extra for additional servers.

So even though, as others have already answered, technically you can use your certificate on different servers, there may be other restrictions.

---

<sup>1)</sup>  for instance [Symantec](https://www.websecurity.symantec.com/ssl-certificate/secure-site-wildcard) will currently still charge $1999,- for a wildcard certificate and $1595,- for each additional server....

Comment: Those who have money to pay $1999 for a certificate wouldn't be asking this question, though. ;)

Comment: I have worked with too many companies where purchasing decisions are made so far away from the IT department that concepts such as "cost" and "value" were no longer any concern for an engineer that needs to get things done. Only compliance was needed...